# Ansible - Filter Dictionary Values

Tags: ansible, filtering, ansible-module

I have gathered the list of all users using [getent_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html):

```
- name: Get user info
  getent:
    database: passed
```

This returns this variable as getent_passwd, a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "uuidd": [
        "x",
        "107",
        "112",
        "",
        "/run/uuidd",
        "/usr/sbin/nologin"
    ],
    "www-data": [
        "x",
        "33",
        "33",
        "www-data",
        "/var/www",
        "/usr/sbin/nologin"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to return an array of users, including some specific users, finding the key of item.value in which "/home" is a part of one of the value array items and "nologin" is not.
This is the code I have written so far, but it is not correct.

```
- name: style the user list
  set_fact:
    my_users: "{{ item.key | default([]) }}"
  when:
    - "'nologin' not in (item.value)"
    - "'/home' search in (item.value)"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', getent_passwd) }}"
```

How should I change my conditions to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you understood correctly, since pattern/regex matching works on strings and not on items of list, `when` condition won't work. While matching items from a list, we need to match the complete item, i.e.

```
when:
  - "'/home/someuser' in item.value"
  - "'/usr/sbin/nologin' not in item.value"
```

Typically, the `$HOME` path in Linux is `/home/$USER`. The resulting `getent_passwd` contains the username in `item.key`. Which means that we can use `/home/{{ item.key }}` to match in `item.value`.

A task such as below should do the job:

```yaml
    - name: save users with actual login
      set_fact:
        my_users: "{{ my_users | default([]) + [ item.key ] }}"
      when:
        - "'/home/' ~ item.key in item.value"
        - "'/usr/sbin/nologin' not in item.value"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', getent_passwd) }}"
```

The other approach could be to actually `join` the `item.value` to get a string similar to the one in `/etc/passwd` so that we can do text search such as: `'/home' search in (item.value)`.

Example:

```yaml
   # item.value | join(':') is the same as each line of '/etc/passwd'
    - name: save users with actual login
      set_fact:
        my_users: "{{ my_users | default([]) + [ item.key ] }}"
      when:
        - "'/home' in item.value | join(':')"
        - "'nologin' not in item.value | join(':')"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', getent_passwd) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension of the other answer with additional check to exclude system users:

```
- name: save users with actual login
  set_fact:
    actual_users: "{{ actual_users | default([]) + [ item.key ] }}"
  when:
    - "item.value[1] | int >= 1000"
    - "'/home' in item.value[4]"
    - "'nologin' not in item.value[5]"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', getent_passwd) }}"
```